# How to put "NULL" in empty table fields?

Tags: sql

I am connecting to an SQL DB to take some information from a table and showing it on one of my web pages. Some fields in the SQL table are *NULL* but when the data is shown on my page it just shows an empty field without the table border etc.

I would like to have the word "*NULL*" in those empty fields but not sure how you go about it. I am sure it's pretty simply but I can't find anything to show me how.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your SQL query to the question?

Comment: HTML is not a programming language. This question lacks the most basic info: what your language is and what your code looks like.

Comment: What is stopping you from simply putting that word where you want it?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using MySQL, you can use [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT COALESCE(columnname, 'NULL') AS alias
```

Comment: I normally prefer to do it in the client language so I can add additional markup to distinguish a NULL column from a literal "NULL" string and I don't need to tweak all my queries. Of course, we have no idea of what language we're talking about :)

Comment: I think it is better to `convert/cast` and then check for null  as `coalesce(convert(varchar(max), columnname),'null')` since we don't know the data type of the column.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
SELECT
  CASE when columnname is NULL then 'NULL' else columnname end AS alias
...
```